# regex - Allow only one space and one hypen in a name

Tags: javascript, regex

Currently, my regex is allowing for multiple spaces and hyphens but simply not allowing them one after another in a name.

Currently it allows for multiple spaces and hypens:

```
vjbn-bjnlm-bnj-

gvjhb vgbhjk vghj

vgjbh-vgh vghb vghbj-
```

How would I adjust this to ONLY allow for 1 of space or hypen EACH:

```
jhbn-vgbh vghjbj
```

My current regex is:

```
/^[À-ÿA-Za-z]+(?:[À-ÿA-Za-z]+|([-' ])(?!\1))*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning, you can add negative lookahead for `.+-.+-`, thus excluding strings with more than one dash, and then use the same sort of pattern again to exclude strings with more than one space:

```
^(?!.+-.+-)(?!.+ .+ )[À-ÿA-Za-z]+(?:[À-ÿA-Za-z]+|([-' ])(?!\1))*
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/61kC3C/1

Comment: This would accept things like `foo -bar`.  Maybe the OP is OK with that, or maybe not.

Comment: Thats IT. Wow thank you so much for your help. Just made my day :)

Comment: @JakeMetz When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)